# How to get the following 100% Stacked bar chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm new to Power BI. I can plot a 100% stacked bar chart flawlessly in Plotly Python. However, when I tried to do the same thing on Power BI, I'm not succeeding.

The plot plot is here: [stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBd6x.png)

**The column names are x-labels, the stacks are unique values of the column, the y axis has the count of the stacks for each column.**

What fields should I select for axis, legend, values, and tooltips to achieve the same in Power BI?

A snapshot of the data fields in BI is here:[fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Pvw.png)

All the 23 fields have the same five values: Strongly agree to Strongly disagree, as shown in the legend of the stacked bar chart.

A snapshot of the table. Each row is a survey response from a single respondent.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcqAl.png)

Comment: why your 23 value is separate 23 column? They have to be in one single column with level in another column. Then you can achieve your desired output. If I am wrong, show your table structure with some sample data.

Comment: MR @R_R please find the table structure snapshot. I added it to the question. 
Looking forward to hearing from you!

Response to each question of the survey is one single column and each column has 5 options the survey responders can choose to answer. Hence, these are different columns. However, the end goal is to achieve something like the stacked barchart i have attached in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider 5 column in your table for test purpose as below-

[image]

Now you need some transformation in your source data. Select **All columns** and apply **Unpivot Columns** from the ribbon's **Transformation** tab and you will get results as below-

[image]

**Now** get back to report by clicking **Close & Apply** button, and create this below measure-

```
count_ = COUNT(your_table_name_1[Value])
```

**Finally** configure your 100% Stacked Column Chart as below-

[image]

**And** here is the output (**considering 5 questions**)-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Appreciate the answer. It's perfect!!!

Comment: You are most welcome. Nice to see it helped. You can also put an up vote for the answer :)